# Objects in Array Stretched and Deformed with Curve Modifier

Tags: modifiers

I have a chain object, and I have a curve it follows. I got it to work for following curve, but chain object are not circles but both parts are more like stretched circles (ovals).

Object I made with two toruses one rotated 90 degrees and then joined them together. I tried single torus too, but same issue persists, on a curve it just looks like a stretched oval.

What is the issue?

Comment: can you upload file? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Dont use the curve modifier directly on the torus. Use the torus as dupliface on a plane with the array and curve modifiers instead

Comment: I forgot to say that that i have 2 active modifiers. One is array and other is curve.

Answer (score 18):

The curve modifier distorts the objects, that is the intended behavior. If you want an undeformed array use  either by *Instancing* (*Duplifaces* before 2.8*) or a particle system instead.

Add your *Array*+*Curve* modifier stack to a simple plane mesh instead.

Create a new plane mesh, parent one single chain link to it and activate *Object Properties > Instancing > Faces* (*Duplifaces* pre 2.8*)on the plane's object properties.

Then add the *Array* modifier, use an empty object rotated $90º$ to introduce rotation to each link. Activate the *Object Offset* option and pick the empty.

Adjust spacing and settings as desired, and then add the curve modifier exclusively to the plane object alone.

[image: Array+Curve+Duplifaces]

Alternatively use a particle system instead of *Instancing > Faces* feature with one particle per face if you wish to hide the original link independently. Manually adjust particle count to match the number of arrayed links.

Comment: ok i followed this animation but when i use array it only multiplies the plane

Comment: But I thank you for taking your time. i will see some tutorials and info about dublifaces and hopefully can figure out what to do. Thanks a lot

Comment: You have to parent the torus to the plane

Comment: How do you stop the plane from being rendered?

Comment: Which part didn't work for you in 2.8? I just managed to follow along just fine. Also if you search you will find what you seek https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118835/eevee-particles-hide-mesh-emitter-at-render/118841#118841

Comment: Thanks, this works but I don't understand the purpose of the plane and parenting the torus to it.  Once I got it working, I deleted the plane and nothing changed.  Is the plane there to reduce deformation of the torus?  In my question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/295991/simple-array-along-bezier-curve-3-5-1-not-working-the-way-i-expect?noredirect=1#comment510208_295991 I had significant torus deformation but did not use the plane.

Comment: The faces determine where the torus will be placed preventing distortions

Answer (score 0):

For modern versions of Blender with Geometry Nodes available, a friendlier approach can be used.

[image: Chain Curve]

1. Add a *Geometry Nodes* modifier to your bezier curve.
2. Use a *Curve to Points* node set to *Length*, and adjust the *Length* as desired.
3. After that use an *Instance on Points* node
4. Add whatever geometry you like to the *Instance* socket. In the illustrated case I constructed a torus (from a curve circle and a *Curve to Mesh* node, but you can use any bespoke object instead)
5. To rotate every other instance you can use a *Rotate Instances* node
6. Under the *Selection* socket connect an *Index* node to identify which instances to rotate
7. Between the to add a *Math* node set to *Modulo* of $2$, to only select every other instance

[image: Geometry Nodes Instance on curve]