# How to align duplication correct way

Tags: bezier-curves, dupli-groups

With the reference image attach. Im making the sandals and im the way to plug the diamonds in that. I have remove the center edge from the mesh. With the duplication im making the diamond to rotate around the curve. From side view it looks good but when i rotate and see the diamond going upper side and some diamond gone inside the mesh and only 1 diamond ring is visible. How correct align with the reference image the diamonds.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier

Comment: @lemon may i know why i have to add a plane and empty is it necessary can you make it clear

Comment: I think the empty is not needed for you. About the plane: this is a way to avoid the diamonds to be deformed if they are directly curved. So as the diamond is dupliface of the plane, it is not deformed even if the curved plane array is deformed. But sometimes these deformations are not so much visible, so you can also curve an arrayed diamond directly (just try what is the best in your case)

Comment: @lemon after adding the plane and set fit curve there are no duplicate are performing i have attach the file above what im missing

Comment: Have you activated dupliface on the plane, after the parenting?

Comment: @lemon yes i have activated the plane

Comment: Could you upload the file again?

Comment: I have got the answer but i want to learn different methods also for future so i do prefer your answer also plz this is the file [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2871" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2871/)

Comment: I think you just missed to check 'faces' in the 'duplication' section of the plane's property panel (not visible in this new blend file as the parenting is not done). This is called 'dupliface' also (like you checked 'dupliframe' in the first blend file). Get it?... and before doing that, apply the scale on the plane (or the result will be very large)

Comment: @lemon with the reference video i have made that duplication its on frame not faces. What is difference between faces and frames Thanks https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rp88ckdLwVQ

Comment: Dupliframe is for objects that have no faces. And I suggested duplifaces for the plane you attempted to use yesterday. Also, you can use this plane (faces) to give an orientation if needed. Another aspect: if you were rendering an animation dupliframe will correspond to each frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the curve selected, under the *Curve* tab of the properties area, activate **Follow**.

[image: follow path animation]

Go into *Edit Mode* and change the curve's **Tilt** so that the curve's arrows are perpendicular to the shoe geometry. With a control point selected use *Curve* > *Control Points* > *Tilt* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to do that. I suggest enabling **Proportional Editing** to achieve a smooth transition. (The tilt can also be changed after the diamonds are aligned, which probably will make errors more obvious.)

[image: curve tilt]

Change the diamonds' **Rotation** so that the diamonds are aligned with the surface.
XYZ angles of 0°, -15° and -90° seem to work fine.

[image: angles]

To make sure that the curve is running at the surface of the shoe, add a *Shrinkwrap Modifier* with the shoe as target, mode being *Nearest Surface Point* and enable *Apply on Spline*.

[image: apply on spline]

You might have to move some of the curve's control points outwards so that the shrinkwrap modifier doesn't snap the diamonds to the inside of the shoe.

[image: shrinkwrap]

Final blend file:

[image]

Comment: I did notice @lemon 's suggestion of adding a plane array with dupli-faces after I started my answer and I do think that the plane array method is superior as it would allow you to use a shrinkwrap modifier on the planes, which again would allow you to skip the fixing of the curve's tilt. Or at least be much more sloppy with it.

Comment: Problem was it there were no dupliframe made by array after activating also. Any way thanks for both

Comment: @ateks, for the plane, not 'dupliframe', but 'dupliface' (which means duplicate the children objects for each face of the parent object)