# Make Bezier Curve look like Torus Array

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I am just sitting here at my very first own project and just thinking if it is possible to make a bezier curve look like a torus array like seen in example picture. Hope anyone can tell me how to do if possible. 
I have already tried using a simple torus array and made it follow a bezier curve but first of all it got pretty stretched out at some point but second and most important it was nearly impossible getting this thing into exact position I need, which is pretty difficult. But at all other ideas are welcome.

Thanks for the attention. :)

[image]

Comment: Not exactly what you want but the technique explained here may also be of help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier/68925#68925

Comment: This is so totally helpful for another thing I will need for this project in near future, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is the Curve modifier.

In the following screenshot you can see a torus mesh to which I added an Array modifier and a Curve modifier.  The curve modifier refers to the Bezier curve.

I had to rotate the torus array 90 degrees around the Y axis because it seems the curve array defaults ton the X axis.  I guess I could have picked a different deformation axis if I had noticed that radio button array earlier.

[image: torus array modified to follow a curve]

Comment: Good Idea, can I put the Bezier right into the Array so I can precisely modify and put it how I need it? Never used this modifier. :)

Comment: The bezier is a separate object.  If you are going to link them at all (it is perfectly reasonable for the bezier and the mesh to have no relationship other than the modifier) it would probably make the most sense for the bezier curve to be the parent object of the mesh.  That makes it slightly easier to translate, rotate, and scale them together by just altering the curve that is the parent.