# Follow bezier with scale variation

Tags: bezier-curves, scale

Could you help me please?
I need to a pattern where spheres are following a bezier curve without deformation, touching each other but with different scales in some parts of bezier line. The spheres must not intersect with each other and there may be no gaps between them, like in the example picture (blue line is bezier):
[image: Example]

My attempts with duplicaces failed:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier

Comment: It is similar by not solves it. I need spheres follow path, be not deformed and the main part is scaling down or up in different parts like in the picture. the goal is to control scale and don't let spheres intersect or go apart while they stay not deformed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick here is using the same technique as described in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier), but tick the option *Scale* for *Duplifaces*.

1. Just create one plane mesh, make sure it is 1x1 units in size. Make sure you apply its scale if you scale it in *Object Mode*.
2. Create you sphere, at the same scene coordinate as your plane. Also scale it so it is 1x1x1 units in size. Make sure you apply its scale if you scale it in *Object Mode*.
3. Create your Bezier curve object, adjust shape as desired but make sure it stays at the same scene coordinate as your plane and sphere.
4. Create one Empty object type and scale it to 95% scale (or adjust as desired). Once again make sure it stays at the same scene coordinate as your plane, and sphere.

[image]

5. Add an *Array* modifier to the plane, set the Empty as *Object Offset* and adjust the relative spacing so it matches the scale factor of the empty. In my case for 95% scale the *Relative Offset* should be 0.975.

[image]

6. Now just parent the sphere to the plane, activate *Duplifaces* and tick the option *Scale* so duplis are sized according to face area.
7. Adjust the Array as necessary.

[image]