# Controlling the scale of objects without distortion when tapering arrays on a curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, scale

I want to find a way to scale an array of objects along the curve, such that the scale of an object is proportional to the position on the curve, or can be adjusted along its length.

[image: Spheres along a curve]

With my understanding of the Array and Curve modifiers, the object will be positioned based on its proximity with the next object in the array. I'm able to change the radius of the curve at its points and this does scale the array at that point, however only at the axes not following the curve, so this produces ellipsoid at that point.

[image: I don't want ellipsoids there, just smaller spheres!]

I've tested out the object offset option on the array modifier, using an empty at the origin point. It produced the taping spheres that I was looking for, but that only did the scaling one way and no longer respected the length of the array.

[image: This object mode seems very limited to me!]

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98648/follow-bezier-with-scale-variation/98672#98672

Comment: Also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier/68925#68925