# How to duplicate object along extracted curve?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I have a curve that I extracted from my main object - a boulder. Now I want a "step" object to duplicate along that curve, but I get some weird, unexpected, undesired results using Array+Curve mods. I have applied transforms to both objects. 
[image: Initial Mesh and the curve to be followed]

[image: Result after Array+Curve]

Comment: What do you mean by unexpected? If you mean each boulder is distorted along the curve, the following link will help. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier

Comment: Are the origins for the curve and the object on the same place?

Answer (score 1):

No modifier required when using a curve:

1. create your curve, make sure the radius, weights, tilt along the curve are as desired (otherwise it will scale/rotate your mesh...):
   [image]
2. assign your object to the curve and clear the origin (Alt-O)
   [image]
   [image]
3. For your model, select Duplication/frame, uncheck "Speed" and set the number of instances you want in the "end" field
   [image]
4. For the curve, set the same number of frames as in 3. in the Path Animation section, set the Evaluation Time as 0 and check Follow if you want your mesh to have its direction follow the curve (I guess you want to uncheck it in your case):
   [image]
5. select your original mesh then Shift-Ctrl-A to "Make Duplicate Real".
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried it, and I realized I need Z rotation to exist, since the paths have to be duplicated. But I'm not sure how to do this, other than manually, because Follow makes those duplicates dizzy.

Comment: what do you mean "I need Z rotation to exist"?

Comment: I mean that I want the steps to individually rotate around their Z (pivot set to an end vertex) so they rotate (about 20-30 deg) for each duplicate. 
Think spiral staircase.

Comment: this can be set on your curve by tweaking each bezier control point (weight, radius, tilt in edit mode/transform panel)