# Build long mesh along bezier curve while using different meshes

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

So how would you go about making a long piece of pipe and use different meshes along the way.

For example I have one perfect straight piece, one with a dent and another just like the first but with different UV map.

I know you can have caps but can you in some way build it from different pieces?

Ideally I'd like to have a bezier curve to control the placement and then Array+Curve modifier on the mesh to extrude it along the Bezier. But how do you add variation to that other than do it manually? Is there a way to add and align multiple bezier curves one after another?

I thought about vertex groups but bezier curves don't support them?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/113973/place-spawn-objects-along-curve-with-randomized-scale-and-rotation also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier

Comment: While OP seemed happy with the first link, I am skeptical it will actually solve the problem. Additional, the OP seems to be having issues with the provided answer, as they added an answer requesting help to the linked question. I suggest this be left open so a better solution to this specific problem (which is different) can be provided.