# Place/spawn objects along curve with randomized scale and rotation?

Tags: bezier-curves, procedural

Is possible to place/spawn objects along curve with randomized scale and rotation?
I'm looking for lazy way to create flowers and randomized procedural patterns.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use a particle system.

[image]

Use the [techniques described in my answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier) to array a small plane ver a curve. Add an *Array* modifier set to fit curve and and a *Curve* modifier afterwards to a small plane or object that will be the base for ditributing your flowers.

Instead of *Duplifaces* as described in the answer add a new particle system to your plane object.

Turn on the option to *Use Modifier Stack*, emit from faces without *Random* and *Even distribution*. Then set *Particles per face* to 1 (if you desired a perfect single item alignement).

Under the *Render* Panel  of your particle system set it to either *Object* and pick your flower object or *Group* if you have a set different ones to distribute.

Turn on both *Unborn* and *Died* and turn off *Emitter*. You may also need to disable the physics set to *None*

You can now control the size randomness from the *Random Size* property under the *Render* panel.

[image]

Adjust particle count as necessary to match the number of arrayed items.

Comment: Thanks [final](https://i.imgur.com/XqZEn14.png) result in my game