# Issue with z rotation with spawned objects from group along curve

Tags: modifiers, particles

I am trying to build a wall using grouped objects, particles and arrays as described here:
[Place/spawn objects along curve with randomized scale and rotation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/113973/place-spawn-objects-along-curve-with-randomized-scale-and-rotation/114066)

A link was provided to a solution but I can't get it to work. My issue is that I can't get my objects to rotate along the path. I just get long string of objects following the curve but all have the same global rotation. I've made an example blend with a wall: https://www11.zippyshare.com/v/hHOCX15J/file.html How do I get the walls to follow the curve z rotation? To be a continuous wall.

Comment: Please don't remove to body altering the question beyond recognition. Even if there aren't any answers right now, there may be someone who will read this question in the future and can answer it. It would help if you edited your question with example images of the current state and the desired state (a mockup). Also, please share your files with [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).