# is it possible to use the array modifier to follow an edge instead of going straight?

Tags: modifiers, workflow

[image]

i'm trying to have this fence follow an edge what is the best none destructive way to go about it

Comment: You mean the horizontal planks to follow the stake on the right?

Comment: i meant everything i have selected to follow an inset rectangle on the plane underneath

Comment: Probably you should use a curve (instead of the rectangle) and add a curve modifier after the array.

Comment: alright thanks i'll try that

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier/68925 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/113973/place-spawn-objects-along-curve-with-randomized-scale-and-rotation/113989 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49639/how-to-smooth-an-arrayed-object-so-the-breaks-between-objects-are-less-obvious/49651