# Repeating objects along a path without altering geometry

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm trying to line up duplications of one and the same object using an Array Modifier and a path/curve. You can think of a line of dominos: They are repeatedly lined up behind each other with some space between them (Array Modifier).

I tried using a Curve Modifier, but the problem is that the modifier will alter the objects geometry by making it bend; that would be perfect for a road or train track, but I just want my dominos to follow the curve, not to alter their geometry.

So, is there any easy way to do this that I totally missed? I never worked with curves/paths before, so I'm pretty unaware of their options.

Comment: You probably want to be looking at [dupliframes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliframes.html), or possibly [dupliverts](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliverts.html), if you prefer to change your curve into a mesh before using it as an arranging tool.

Comment: This question has been asked before, see Possible duplicate of [Torus object stretched in array curve modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier)