# Make object follow curve without rotating/deforming

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm trying to make a functioning escalator. I've got an array of stairs with a curve modifier and a bezier circle for the path. When a stair is on the parts of the curve that bend, the stairs rotate and deform with the bend. How can I stop this? Thanx.
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier

Answer (score 3):

<sub>This answer will describe the creation of a single "tile" of the escalator.</sub>

[image]

Add a bone with a follow path constraint with *Follow Curve* checked. I also checked *Fixed Position* and animated the offset value.

Add a smaller bone (*OrientationBone*) beneath it and parent it to the original bone. When the bone is ascending the *OrientationBone* will be beneath it, and when it is ascending it will be above it.

[image: bone setup]

Because bone > bone driver relation create a cyclic dependency error in 2.79, I added an empty.

I used a **copy location** and a **copy rotation** constraint from the bone to the empty.

Next, add a limit rotation constraint to the empty with all values at `0` and all axes checked. Add a driver to that constraints influence. Use the Y Location of the Bone as a driver variable. Whenever the Y Location is between 0 and 6 (orange in the gif below) in my case, the bone is ascending and the driver should return the value `1` to enable the limit rotation constraint and stop the empty from rotation during the ascent. I achieved this with constant keyframes of the driver.

[image]

I added another driver for the descend, which will first check if the bone is descending with the help of the orientation bone. If the Y Location of the OrientationBone is smaller than the Y Location of the Bone, the bone is descending, otherwise the driver should return `0`.

[image]

Comment: Very interesting. I kind of figured I'd have to use a completely different method. I really appreciate your taking the time to help.