# How to add horizontal cylinder at end of cube

Tags: modeling

I have this cube which has the basic shape of an escalator but I want to add a horizontal cylinder at the end of the cube like an escalator how can I do that

[image: screenshot]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127754/make-object-follow-curve-without-rotating-deforming/127767#127767

Answer (score 4):

You could select the last top and bottom edges and create bevels, then extrude inwards and merge.

[image]

Comment: Should I always extrude inwards and merge when creating bevels? For example in a cube with just small bevelled corners?

Comment: no you don't always have to, but to keep quads and tris you'll need to use join and knife