# How do i make an object follow a line correctly?

Tags: bezier-curves, obj, curve-modifier

So i want an object (A dragon) to follow this line, which begins and travels normel with a slight bend and after some time it goes into a sprial and ends, the line has points in all coordinations, meaning some are higher some lower, some right, some left. But my dragon, no matter what deform axes i use flys off to some weird shape and changes form. I dont want the dragon to strech nor to goe somewhere else, i only want it to look normal and follow the line. I also applyed all transformation and set the orgigens to the right places. I appreciate the help.

Comment: just let a (invisible) plane (or whatever object) follow the line. Then parent your dragon to that plane.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127754/make-object-follow-curve-without-rotating-deforming?rq=1