# I want this dragon with its rig to follow this line

Tags: rigging, armature, bezier-curves, rigidbody, curve-modifier

So i want this dragon, rather the skeleton of the Dragon, to follow this bezier Curve. But my problem is that the rig doesnt change the form of the dragon, allthough they are parent. Also only the middle part of the dragon should follow the Curve and the legs should be on the line. Moreover i scaled the dragon up to 100x its normal size, since for some this help, but it doesnt for me.
Here is the File:
https://workupload.com/file/EDUENfwQ6bm

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Hello and welcome! ...which dragon? ...which line? Maybe it would be good if you add images and further information to your question, which will be preserved even if external links are no longer available. Please use https://blend-exchange.com/. This way you would invite others to look at your question and answer it. Thank you!

Comment: I found this when I searched for animating a snake on a path. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133012/line-of-bones-to-travel-and-conform-to-curve-train-or-snake-following-path

Comment: @Texaler Please instead of creating a new Question edit your original one https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/282316/how-do-i-make-an-object-follow-a-line-correctly Thank you