# Place collection instances using an array-type UI?

Tags: modifiers, collections

Collection instances don't support modifiers, so laying out a bunch of them with an "Array" modifier doesn't seem to be possible.

But I love the ease and control Arrays give me. Is there any way to lay out collection instances that is *like* the Array UI (be able to specify a number of instances, their relative distance apart, etc.) rather than just Duplicating over-and-over again?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923

Comment: There is also commercial addon [Distribute Objects](https://blendermarket.com/products/distribute-objects-addon) Full disclaimer I am the author