# Simple Array along bezier curve; 3.5.1 not working the way I expect

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, curve-modifier

I've watched a few videos on how to put an array object on a curve and the instruction seem very simple.  Create a bezier curve, create an object (e.g. torus).  Add an array mod to the torus and set the Fit Type to Fit Curve and add a Curve mod and set the Curve Object to the Bezier.

Instead of getting an array of tori following the curve, I get deformed ovals, much larger than my tori.  Before you tell me that I have a fixed count on the array, not 'fit to curve', I have similar distortion from the Fit Curve option in the Array fit type.

I must be missing some simple secret to making this work in 3.5.1.  It seems like it should be easy but the results are way off.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier

Comment: If the page linked by Duarte doesn't answer, please share your file