# Array mirrored object around curve

Tags: animation, modifiers, bezier-curves, transforms

I'm trying to recreate a scene from the opening sequence of No Time To Die:
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awZQdw_iNZY&list=RDawZQdw_iNZY&index=2&ab_channel=HDFilmTributes)

There are two problems with my scene. First, some of the weapons are deformed when I array them around the curve. The second problem is that they do not array around the whole curve.

[image]

---

Here's the project file. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: array a plane, activate the Instancing > Face option of the plane, and parent the gun to the plane? This way the gun won't be deformed by the gun

Comment: good idea, it works now thank you. Still having the problem that it doesnt array around the whole curve tho.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/objects-in-array-stretched-and-deformed-with-curve-modifier

Answer (score 3):

Your curve is made of several curves (in *Edit* mode press <kbd>L</kbd> on the curve and you'll see that you'll only select a segment of the spiral), here is why the array doesn't follow it correctly, you need to fix it manually (not sure there's a *Merge by Distance* for curves). Also in *Object* mode right click on the gun and *Set Origin > Geometry to Origin* so that the object is aligned with the curve. At last the gun object will be deformed by the curve modifier so you should proceed another way.

The solution can be to array a plane instead of your gun, activate the *Object > Instancing > Faces* option of the plane object, parent the gun to the plane.

Comment: yes i was able to connect them by just pressing F and it works now. Thanks for your help!