# How to create pavement and ceiling for a curved wall

Tags: curve-modifier

As you can see from the attached image, I am currently working on a curved hallway made of single brick walls, which I started from: how can I create a pavement and a ceiling following the hallway?

[image]

Another thing: in the hallway there should be some circular ceiling lights which should follow the curve without deforming, how is possible to maintain their shape?

[image]

Comment: Hello, are your bricks supposed to be curvy or straight?

Comment: What type of pavement are you looking for ? Should pavement bend along the hallway or be uniform ? What kind of solution do you want : manual modeling, geometry nodes, something else ?

Comment: I need a uniform pavement which follow the course of hallway (inside), made manually.

Comment: You could give an Array and a Curve modifier to a plane, enable Instancing > Faces of the plane, then parent the brick to the plane?

Comment: Could you please show me how to proceed? Sorry, but I am still learning...

Comment: About the ceiling light, may I recommend to read this post: [Objects in Array Stretched and Deformed with Curve Modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/68923/177431) ?

Answer (score 3):

It must be doable in Geometry Nodes. If you want to do it with modifiers, you can create your curve, create a plane, put it at the same location as the curve, give it an *Array* modifier (*Fit Curve* mode) and a *Curve* modifier (with the curve as *Curve Object*):

[image]

Keep the plane selected and in the *Object* panel enable the *Instancing > Faces* option. Then create a brick segment (see image) and parent it to the plane, the brick will be instanced on each plane:

[image]

Do the same for the other wall and for the lights.
File: [image]

Comment: Thank you, I do appreciate your help and I have tried but I find it very difficult...

Comment: Please share your file with your try

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=9vg9k5zN" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/9vg9k5zN/)

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't look like you've tried the method I recommend, please see my edit and check my file